# copy webpage part/paragraph with curl or file_get_contents

Tags: curl, web, copy

So guys, I took a brief look at curl documentation and file_get_contents but I was
unable to find something that really matches my needs. I'm sorta new in php and it's
modules so I'm asking for some help. Now all the examples show how to copy an
entire url. What If I need to copy just a paragraph of the website. Just the article
title or subtitle how do I do that? Is there anyway I can specify some parameters to
for example fech just this part from a given web page:

```
<div id="newscontent">
//text content
</div>
```

Thank you alot guys.
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think curl can process the html content. You have to use either an XML parser on it or you can use regular expressions (preg_match, preg_match_all functions) to find the specific element if you know the element ID.

A simple regular expression example would be here:

http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Thank you my friend for taking time to respond to me.